# How can I connect to docker db from local django?

Tags: django, docker, redis

How can I connect to docker db from local django?

```
version: '3'

services:

  redis-1:
    container_name: redis1
    build: ./docker/redis
    environment:
      X_REDIS_PORT: 7001
    networks:
      redisnet:
        ipv4_address: 10.0.0.11
    ports:
      - 7001:7001

  redis-2:
    container_name: redis2
    build: ./docker/redis
    environment:
      X_REDIS_PORT: 7002
    networks:
      redisnet:
        ipv4_address: 10.0.0.12
    ports:
      - 7002:7002

  redis-3:
    container_name: redis3
    build: ./docker/redis
    environment:
      X_REDIS_PORT: 7003
    networks:
      redisnet:
        ipv4_address: 10.0.0.13
    ports:
      - 7003:7003

  redis-4:
    container_name: redis4
    build: ./docker/redis
    environment:
      X_REDIS_PORT: 7004
    networks:
      redisnet:
        ipv4_address: 10.0.0.14
    ports:
      - 7004:7004

  redis-5:
    container_name: redis5
    build: ./docker/redis
    environment:
      X_REDIS_PORT: 7005
    networks:
      redisnet:
        ipv4_address: 10.0.0.15
    ports:
      - 7005:7005

  redis-6:
    container_name: redis6
    build: ./docker/redis
    environment:
      X_REDIS_PORT: 7006
    networks:
      redisnet:
        ipv4_address: 10.0.0.16
    ports:
      - 7006:7006

  redis-cluster:
    container_name: redis-cluster
    image: redis:latest
    command: redis-cli -p 7001 --cluster create 10.0.0.11:7001 10.0.0.12:7002 10.0.0.13:7003 10.0.0.14:7004 10.0.0.15:7005 10.0.0.16:7006 --cluster-replicas 1 --cluster-yes
    depends_on:
      - redis-1
      - redis-2
      - redis-3
      - redis-4
      - redis-5
      - redis-6
    networks:
      redisnet:
        ipv4_address: 10.0.0.2

  predixy:
    container_name: predixy
    build: ./docker/predixy
    depends_on:
      - redis-1
      - redis-2
      - redis-3
      - redis-4
      - redis-5
      - redis-6
    ports:
      - 7617:7617
    volumes:
      - ./docker/predixy/conf:/etc/predixy/conf
    networks:
      redisnet:
        ipv4_address: 10.0.0.3

networks:

  redisnet:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 10.0.0.0/16
```

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file and I would like to connect the predixy (cluster proxy) floated on port 7617 with django as below.

```
# settings.py
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "redis://0.0.0.0:7617/",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
        },
    }
}
```

```
failed to connect to Redis: Connection refused (os error 111)
```

However, django does not seem to be able to connect to predixy.

For your information, I also upload the predixy file.

```
# docker/predixy/predixy.conf
################################### GENERAL ####################################
## Predixy configuration file example

## Specify a name for this predixy service
## redis command INFO can get this
Name PredixyExample

## Specify listen address, support IPV4, IPV6, Unix socket
## Examples:
# Bind 127.0.0.1:7617
# Bind 0.0.0.0:7617
# Bind /tmp/predixy

## Default is 0.0.0.0:7617
Bind 10.0.0.3:7617

## Worker threads
WorkerThreads 4

## Memory limit, 0 means unlimited

## Examples:
# MaxMemory 100M
# MaxMemory 1G
# MaxMemory 0

## MaxMemory can change online by CONFIG SET MaxMemory xxx
## Default is 0
MaxMemory 0

## Close the connection after a client is idle for N seconds (0 to disable)
## ClientTimeout can change online by CONFIG SET ClientTimeout N
## Default is 0
ClientTimeout 300


## IO buffer size
## Default is 4096
# BufSize 4096

################################### LOG ########################################
## Log file path
## Unspecify will log to stdout
## Default is Unspecified
Log ./predixy.log

## LogRotate support

## 1d rotate log every day
## nh rotate log every n hours   1 <= n <= 24
## nm rotate log every n minutes 1 <= n <= 1440
## nG rotate log evenry nG bytes
## nM rotate log evenry nM bytes
## time rotate and size rotate can combine eg 1h 2G, means 1h or 2G roate a time

## Examples:
# LogRotate 1d 2G
# LogRotate 1d

## Default is disable LogRotate


## In multi-threads, worker thread log need lock,
## AllowMissLog can reduce lock time for improve performance
## AllowMissLog can change online by CONFIG SET AllowMissLog true|false
## Default is true
# AllowMissLog false

## LogLevelSample, output a log every N
## all level sample can change online by CONFIG SET LogXXXSample N
LogVerbSample 0
LogDebugSample 0
LogInfoSample 10000
LogNoticeSample 1
LogWarnSample 1
LogErrorSample 1


################################### AUTHORITY ##################################
Include auth.conf

################################### SERVERS ####################################
Include cluster.conf
# Include sentinel.conf
# Include try.conf


################################### DATACENTER #################################
## LocalDC specify current machine dc
# LocalDC bj

## see dc.conf
# Include dc.conf


################################### COMMAND ####################################
## Custom command define, see command.conf
#Include command.conf

################################### LATENCY ####################################
## Latency monitor define, see latency.conf
Include latency.conf
```

```
## redis cluster server pool define
# cluster.conf
ClusterServerPool {
    MasterReadPriority 60
    StaticSlaveReadPriority 50
    DynamicSlaveReadPriority 50
    RefreshInterval 1
    ServerTimeout 1
    ServerFailureLimit 10
    ServerRetryTimeout 1
    Servers {
        + 10.0.0.11:7001
        + 10.0.0.12:7002
        + 10.0.0.13:7003
        + 10.0.0.14:7004
        + 10.0.0.15:7005
        + 10.0.0.16:7006
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem? I'm struggling with this problem.
What I want is to access docker-cli and connect to `redis-cli -h 10.0.0.3 -p 7617` so that I can see the data I put in from local django

Comment: Have you pinged 0.0.0.0:7617 from your host machine to ensure that a predixy service is unavailable on that port?

Comment: @Joe Howard I tried this using tcping. `tcping 0.0.0.0 7617`
`0.0.0.0 port 7617 open.`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Replace 0.0.0.0 with `predixy` as below

```
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "redis://predixy:7617/",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but an error occurred `redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 8 connecting to predixy:7617. nodename nor servname provided, or not known.`